# Can an email speak?

Tags: english-to-german

In English, one would say, "I have received an email from you, which said that..."

Is the direct calque ("Ich habe eine Email von Ihnen bekommen, die sagt, dass...") proper German?

Comment: In this specific case, you could also say "Ich habe eine E-Mail von Ihnen bekommen, laut der ..."